# Safe Operating System - theoreticall

Tags: security, operating-system

What could be the answer for this question:

```
Assume you have a programming language that is claimed to be safe. 
What kind of functionality has to be supported in OS development that is unsafe?
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Very generic question.The language is claimed to be safe how? What's the virtualization level for the OS? Is it on bare metal?

I'd consider unsafe software behaviour that may damage hardware or infiltrate other programs' memory, but the actual list would be dependant on the scope of the OS and the language relationship with the OS (consider: binary errors to JVM errors, the latter potentially much less severe).